# Discord login on my website is not working. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to implement a Discord login on a website. But I have a few issues. When I start the application with `node oauth.js` in the terminal, no error popped  up. But then, when I click on authorize on the Discord website, the following error pops up:

```
 TypeError: fetch is not a function
    at ...\oauth.js:49:5
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (...\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (...\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (...\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (...\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at ...\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (...\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (...\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at ...\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:130:5
    at invokeCallback (...\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)
```

I can't find the error in my code... It's something to do with `fetch`

[My code](https://jsfiddle.net/Atrapfare/6hLfkgun/2/)

Any ideas?

Comment: `fetch` is not a function but a promise because you didn't `await` the `import`. `import` as function is asynchronous (unlike the `import` _statement_ which is used as `import fetch from 'node-fetch'`). But since you are using CommonJS `require` everywhere else, you should probably just change it to `require('node-fetch')`.

Comment: By the way - suggestion for the future: Work on the debugging skills in terms of logically trying to find the reason for what's happening, step by step, comparing things you expect to what really happens, until you found the source of the discrepancy. In this case, I'd have expected a question like `Why does import('node-fetch') return a promise?` and not `Why is my Discord login not working?` - If the error says `fetch is not a function`, the next logical step would be to ask yourself "OK, then what _is_ it?" - which could have been answered by looking at it in a debugger or `console.log`ging

Comment: Then you'd find it's a `Promise`. Since `fetch` comes only from one place in your code - `const fetch = import('node-fetch')` - that means `import('node-fetch')` returned a promise when you expected a function. Searching for that would have probably led to the right answer already (`import` function is async, statement isn't), but if not, _that_ would have been the question to ask. (Also, it could then have looked "out of place" that everything else is `require` and works, but this one is `import` and doesn't, so you could have tried using `require` there too and would have seen it work.)

Comment: Another suggestion: Don't write so many comments. There is no point in commenting `// Send the username with a status code 200.` to `res.status(200).send(response.data.username)` or `// Define "data"` to `data = {` for instance - your code already says that, no reason to communicate the same thing twice! It's just "noise" when reading, and a burden to keep in sync with the actual code upon changes (for example I see you wrote about creating a `FormData` when you actually create a `URLSearchParams` object). Comments exist to convey meaning the actual code _lacks_. Comment _why_, not _what_.

Comment: And one more thing: I don't understand why you are using _two different_ request libraries. Either use `axios` _or_ `node-fetch`, no point in using both...

Comment: Thanks for that detailed answer! The code is from a tutorial, thats why there are so many comments... But there is still an issue. When I use require, it´s still not working. Now the error is: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1089
      throw new ERR_REQUIRE_ESM(filename, parentPath, packageJsonPath);
      ^

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: C:\Users\Dominik\Documents\Development\Websites\Norvex\ucp.norvex.eu\node_modules\node-fetch\src\index.js
require() of ES modules is not supported. - For me, that means u can´t use require here. Any suggetions? :)

Comment: Oh, okay. That's new, in the past this wasn't an issue. In this case the situation is a bit complicated. Easiest way to use existing code is to install v2 instead of v3 of `node-fetch`, but the other ways are explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69055506/how-to-fix-must-use-import-to-load-es-module-discord-js)

Comment: yes i did it and it worked. I found another tutorial, i thinnk this is better than this...

Answer (score 1):

From looking at the fiddle, I can't see any problem except the way you have formatted your `fetch` import.

`const fetch = require('node-fetch');`

Try something like that instead of importing it.

Comment: I already tried this, but then this error pops up: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1089
      throw new ERR_REQUIRE_ESM(filename, parentPath, packageJsonPath);
      ^

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: C:\Users\Dominik\Documents\Development\Websites\Norvex\ucp.norvex.eu\node_modules\node-fetch\src\index.js
require() of ES modules is not supported.

Comment: so i think this isn´t working

Comment: From the docs
"node-fetch is an ESM-only module - you are not able to import it with require. We recommend you stay on v2 which is built with CommonJS unless you use ESM yourself. We will continue to publish critical bug fixes for it."

So you either need to downgrade to v2 or import asynchronously as suggested in the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch)

Comment: how can I downgrade?

Comment: Run **npm i node-fetch@2.6.5**